# VisualStudio 2012 - two projects -> linker error (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

first my simple setup:
I've got 2 VS2012 projects. Now I want to use classes from Project B in Project A.
I added Project B to A's project dependencie list and imported the headers where necessary. (e.g. #include"..\src-pool\Coords.h";).

So far, so good - no compiler errors.
But when I try to build the project, I get some linker errors:

```
Fehler  1   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __thiscall Coords::Coords(double,double)" (??0Coords@@QAE@NN@Z)" in Funktion ""public: void __thiscall TileDownloader::calculateBounds(double *,int)const " (?calculateBounds@TileDownloader@@QBEXPANH@Z)".  C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CPPHA\project\TileDownloader.obj
```

I'm sorry, this is the german version of VS. "Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol" means: Link to not resolved extern symbol.

Any ideas? =)

---

Done this (this is a class I want to export and use in the other project)

Coords.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#ifdef EXPORT_MYCLASS
#define MYCLASSEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYCLASSEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class  MYCLASSEXPORT  Coords
{
public:
    Coords(double lat, double lon);
    ~Coords(void);
    double getLon() const;
    void setLon(double val);
    double getLat() const;
    void setLat(double val);

    void printInfos() const;

private:
    double lat, lon;

};
```

But I get a warning "inconsistent dll export" and the same errors. Sorry, I'm new to C++

---

and I want to use it like this

```
#include "..\src-pool\Coords.h"

class TileDownloader
{
public:
    TileDownloader(void);
    ~TileDownloader(void);


    void  calculateBounds(double* array, int zoomLevel) const;
    void  downloadTiles() const;

private:
    double maxLat, maxLon, minLat, minLon;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things that need to happen for the linker to find the a class method:

1. You reference the right dll/project
2. You have an implementation of that method in that dll/project.
3. It's exposed externally with a dll export (**[__declspec(dllexport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**)

Common practice for declaring an export in a header:

```
#ifdef EXPORT_MYCLASS
#define MYCLASSEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYCLASSEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MyClass
{
     MYCLASSEXPORT MyClass();
}
```

Then you can just define that preprocessor argument in the exporting dll's preprocessor definitions.

In Visual studio:
Project properties -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Prerpocessor deffinitios

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunally it does not work :/ (see above)

Comment: @area404 and did you define EXPORT_MYCLASS in the project's preprocessor definitions (of the exporting dll)?

Comment: @area404 I've edited the post to explain how to define the argument

Comment: Ya, i defined it, but it does not work. Seems like i've made an error elsewhere. The method is implemented and the project is referenced .. hm

Comment: @area404 That warning means that you've either not defined the argument, or defined it in both. You should only define it in the exporting dll project.

Comment: Thank you! I found the last error: the second project's build result was an exe instead of adll